# Devise: Unable to redirect to current user edit profile after sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently working with Rails 6 and Devise for authentication. I would like to redirect a user to edit the form after a successfully signed up. However, after the user signs up, its redirected to root path.

I created `registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to edit_user_path
  end
end
```

Here is the route I'm redirecting too.

```
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                users#edit
                         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                     users#show
```

Here I'm confused as too how to make sure is the current user or would the redirect know is referring to the current user? I'm guessing I would have to do `redirect_to  '/users/#{current_user.id}/edit'`

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
       sessions: 'users/sessions'
     }

  devise_scope :users do
    get 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  root to: 'home#index'

  resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  resources :posts do
    resource :comments, only: %i[show new create edit update]
  end
end
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I removed `redirect_to` because the method takes care of that.

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'registrations'
  }
```